# Video Archive Manager

Tags: c++, database, video, video-recording

I am developing an application in which I need to capture and display as well as record live video feed coming from an input camera or any other source.

I am working on  Windows 7 64 bit machine and building my application in C++ using Visual Studio. Now since I will be archiving all the videos, so along with my application I need to provide a video archive manager which can easily save them and attach tag to the videos based on their name and timestamp and fetch them based on some query. I dont want to write the whole archive manager by my self because of time constraints. So can anyone suggest some open source or even some proprietary tool which can do this for me.

Comment: Do you want a whole program with GUI or a library to integrate with your program?

Comment: I was going to say google/bing is your friend, but from the data that you've given you only need to handle a database table with 3 entries (if storing just file location).

Comment: @CharlesB : Anything will work. If a whole program with GUI is available then its the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want something elaborate, you can use the OS IpropertyStore to update metadata for the file and use Windows Search to retrieve them.

1. [IPropertyStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to update tags
2. [ISearchQueryHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for searching them.

[Developing Property Handlers for Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows more.

Comment: but using IPropertyStore I will only be able to locate my video using windows search. Can I provide my own customized elaborated GUI to the user which provides him all the options such as : Search using the name, Search using the date or tags etc. and at the back I am using windows search to locate video. I mean to say implementation should be completely transparent to user and moreover I am assuming my user is completely lame and hence a GUI is must.